# I get random undefined on variables so Is this overkill for checking if variable is defined and has string length?

Tags: typescript, lodash

It seems like I keep seeing undefines popping up in the app we have where we are referencing
foo.length

Would this be the correct syntaxt for checking if the variable is

- not null
- not undefined
- not empty

Using lodash

```
if(!_.isNil(foo) && foo.length)
```

Or just typescript

```
// option 1
if(foo && foo.length)

// option 2
if(foo)
```

With use of lodash, is it worth even using or is it a performance hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on exactly what the type of that variable is. But if `foo` is `string[] | null | undefined`, then you just check for truthiness and be on your way:

```
if (foo) {
  // foo is `string[]` in this conditional scope
}
```

Or you could use `foo?.length` and provide a default:

```
const size = foo?.length ?? 0 // length of array, if undefined use zero.
```

Using lodash for this sort of thing is way overkill.

---

So given all that to check if the array exists *and* is not empty, this is probably your simplest best:

```
if (foo && foo.length > 0)
```

Comment: I was not familiar with the defaulting syntax. Thank you for the guidance on this.

Comment: That's [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) and the [nullish coallescing operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing). And they're damn handy!